# What is the history of attorney licensing and regulation in the United States, Britain, and the colonies?

Tags: united-states, licensing, unlicensed-practice, history

I'd like to know when law licensing first started, both as to "certification" and as to "licensing" if such a distinction applies in history.  I'd like to know when it began to take hold.  I'd like to get input as to the American Bar Association. And I'd like to know what the founders thought or would have thought about the subject.  And I'd like to know what the prevailing attitude toward lawyering was at the time of the founding.  And anything you could add as to Britain's colonial and precolonial treatment of the profession might be useful too.

All of those things would provide a complete enough answer to my question.  Any further elaboration would be great.

Perhaps this belongs in the history stack exchange.  I don't know.

Comment: FYI: The ABA is not in charge of licensing. Licensing is a function of the courts, and is mostly carried out by arms of the state courts (either a dedicated licensing/discipline agency, or a state bar association acting as an arm of the courts). The ABA accredits law schooks, but states are free to decide whether or not to require an accredited degree.

Comment: That's far too broad a question I think. You could try breaking it up into pieces and you would obtain rather better answers. "Britain" is more than one jurisdiction with very different practices. There's more than one legal profession and they have historically functioned differently (in every part).